# how to create array of errors in mongoose validation based on certain conditions?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

i'm trying to generate array of errors based on certain conditions , how can i achieve that , postman arrises this :  "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"

```
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "username is required"],
    // minlength: 6,
    unique: true,
    // match: [
    //   /^(?=.{3,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/,
    //   "username shouldn't include . or _ and at least 3 letters and at maximum 20 letters",
    // ],
    validate: {
      errors: [],
      validator: function (username) {
        if (username.length < 10) {
          this.errors.push("username cannot be less than 3 characters");
        }
        if (username.match(/(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/)) {
          this.errors.push(`username shouldn't begin or end with . or _ `);
        }
      },
      message: this.errors,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `array` in the `validator` function and `throw` this array as `new Error()`. Then use this array in the callback of the `save()` function.

`validate`

```
validate: {
        validator: function (username) {
            let errors = []
            if (username.length < 3)
                errors.push("username cannot be less than 3 characters")

            if (username.match(/(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/))
                errors.push("username shouldn't begin or end with . or _ ")

            if (errors.length > 0)
                throw new Error(errors)
        }
    }
```

`save`

```
newUser.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        let errors = Object.values(err.errors)[0].properties.message.split(',')
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            err: errors.length > 1 ? errors : errors[0]
        })
    }
    else ...
})
```